# Magento add block to sales order create

Tags: php, magento, adminhtml

I am trying to add a block to the admin create order screen. Im my layout xml I have

```
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fee/fee.js</name></action>
    </reference> 
    <reference name="data">
             <block type="fee/adminhtml_insuranceselector" after="shipping_method" name="fee.insurance" template="fee/sales/order/insuranceselector.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>

<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
    <reference name="data">
             <block type="fee/adminhtml_insuranceselector" after="shipping_method" name="fee.insurance" template="fee/sales/order/insuranceselector.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
```

The block does not show up at all with reference of "data" or even "content", if I change the reference to say "left" it shows up but I really need it in the data area under the shipping method. The content reference doesn't have a template file so I don't see a need to echo a child block. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Although completely unrelated - this post helped me understand why on initial load of an order create I was unable to see my overrides, but on refreshing the page i was able to.  

  Including adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data in addition to admin_html_sales_order_create_index solved my problem!

Comment: @Dylan .
can u please explain me more.actually i m new in magento.i am doing the same but didnt get any response.if i change    <reference name="data"> to    <reference name="left"> then its shows response.

Comment: There actually is a template for the data block that I was not seeing, its its located here: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml

You will need to edit or, or best practice is to overwrite it by copying it to your theme directory. The you will need to call $this->getChildHtml('blockName')

Comment: thanks a ton .. :-) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` block does not display all its children anonymously, you can check its template file (`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml`) to see how it's actually working.

To display your own block below the shipping methods, you will need to apply your own template, based on the original, to the `data` block, and to add a corresponding `getChildHtml` call where you want it to be displayed.