# Add a block on sales order create in admin page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to add a custom block on sales order create page.

here is my code

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>

    <reference name="sidebar">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="verification" template="magentomod/ageverification/sales/order/create/comment.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>

    <reference name="sidebar">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="verification" template="magentomod/ageverification/sales/order/create/comment.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
```

Its work fine but if i change the reference from **sidebar** to **content** or **data** block it not work, i want to add this block within content block.
and i dont want to change in core file of data.phtml.
how do i create own data.phtml file..

lot of confusions.i gone though all the possible answers related to that [Magento add block to sales order create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049033/magento-add-block-to-sales-order-create?rq=1) .please help

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `output="toHtml"` to you block for automaticaly render this block.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="verification" 
          template="magentomod/ageverification/sales/order/create/comment.phtml"
          output="toHtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="verification" 
             template="magentomod/ageverification/sales/order/create/comment.phtml"
             output="toHtml"
        />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
```

and I think you have custom theme, because `content` block have type `list` and all block inside him must be render automaticaly.

Comment: still not displayed..:( i think because of custom plugin...how do i find the problem and also its solution.

Comment: you can show `comment.phtml` may be you can not get needing data for `foreach` for example and you get empty output, you can set `<?php die('comment'); ?>` in first line `comment.phtml` for check loading your block or don't load. @shut why you type block `adminhtml/template` maybe you block should be `core/template`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in your `xml` file.this custom `form.phtml` file display after coupon block.

```
 <adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_items>
              <reference name="items_grid">
                <block type="core/template" template="your_module/sales/order/create/form.phtml" name="your_module_admin_block" after="-" />
            </reference>
        </adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_items>
        <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
            <reference name="items_grid">
               <block type="core/template" template="your_module/sales/order/create/form.phtml" name="your_module_admin_block" after="-" />
            </reference>
        </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
             <reference name="items_grid">
              <block type="core/template" template="your_module/sales/order/create/form.phtml" name="your_module_admin_block" after="-" />
            </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
```